# Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 "rolled back"

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I've tried to upgrade my Kubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04, through the notification popup appeared in my taskbar.

The upgrade process started, it begun to download about 1800 packages, it downloaded almost all of them then the net went down and i decided to resume the upgrade at home.

Connected to my home wifi i restarted the process, the remaining packages were downloaded, the system started to install them. There was no error during packages installation, neither in the "cleanup" process to remove obsolete packages.

I've rebooted after the process was complete but right now seems that i still have a 13.10 installation!

it is written in /etc/lsb-release and the packages installed seems still old.. for example the kernel version is still 3.11..

I didn't see any error message or rollback procedure going on..

Does someone knows what can be happened? if I can find some logs to investigate? I saw in /var/log/apt but there is very little information..

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/issue.net`?

Comment: it only contains "Ubuntu 13.10"